# how to stream tweets for a particular time period in the past

Tags: python, twitter, time, streaming

I am using the following python code to get tweets for a particular topic

```
import sys
from tweepy import *
import time
import csv
CONSUMER_KEY = ''
CONSUMER_SECRET = ''
OAUTH_TOKEN = ''
OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET = ''
class listener(StreamListener):
    def on_data(self,data):
        try:
            saveFile=open('tweetDB2.csv','a')
            saveFile.write(data)
            saveFile.write('\n')
            saveFile.close()
            return True
        except BaseException as e:
            print('failed ondata,',str(e))
            time.sleep(60)
    def on_error(self,status):
        print(status)


auth = OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY,CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(OAUTH_TOKEN,OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET)
twitterStream = Stream(auth,listener())
twitterStream.filter(track=["IPL"])
```

How do I modify the code to get tweets for the same topic but for a different time period (say 2nd week of April,2015)? I went through the API parameters(https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview/request-parameters).But I could not find anything with respect to time period. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think *historical* tweets would be available though the *streaming* API?

Comment: @jonrsharpe OK,I understand the fault.So I have tried to look into a different approach using tweepy.cursor. I am havinig trouble with the since_id and max_id.Can you please tell me in which format should these arguments be entered

Comment: @jonrsharpe given here is the code ... for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search,q="#IPL",count=100,\
                           lang="en",\
                           since_id="Tue Apr 21 00:00:00 +0000 2015",max_id="Wed Apr 22 00:00:00 +0000 2015").items():
    #print(tweet.created_at, tweet.text)
    csvWriter.writerow([tweet.created_at, tweet.text.encode('utf-8')])